# Most efficient way to get bounding rectangle of vector of rectangles

Tags: c++, vector, rectangles

I have an `std::vector` of `cv::Rects` (from the opencv framework) called `rects`, but I suppose the same logic would be applied to any rectangle object, so I'm not going to tag opencv in this question.

I am trying to find the smallest rectangle that encompasses all the rectangles in the vector, this is what I have so far:

```
int t = min_element(rects.begin(), rects.end(), [](cv::Rect a, cv::Rect b){ a.tl().y < b.tl().y;})->tl().y;
int l = min_element(rects.begin(), rects.end(), [](cv::Rect a, cv::Rect b){ a.tl().x < b.tl().x;})->tl().x;
int b = max_element(rects.begin(), rects.end(), [](cv::Rect a, cv::Rect b){ a.br().y < b.br().y;})->br().y;
int r = max_element(rects.begin(), rects.end(), [](cv::Rect a, cv::Rect b){ a.br().x < b.br().x;})->br().x;
cv::Rect smallest_encompassing_rect = cv::Rect(cv::Point(t, l),cv::Point(b, r)))
```

If it's not clear, the `.tl()` function gets the top left point of the rectangle, and `.br()` gets the bottom right.

I know this will work, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to solve the problem. I am working with image processing, so my code is time sensitive.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Passing `Rect` by const reference instead of by value may increase speed.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you, but `Rect` never gets passed, in my code, I only assign it to `smallest_encompassing_rect in the sample code to make the example clear.

Comment: I meant, in your comparer lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't think I can use `std::minimax_element` because the when looking for the min element, I'm comparing the top left corners, and when looking for the max element I'm comparing the bottom right corners

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry thats a typo, fixed it

Comment: You can probably accelerate it by making only one loop instead of four. Not with lambdas, just a regular loop and update `t, l, b, r` in each iteration.

Comment: @A.S.H how can I make this one loop?

Comment: If you don't have any properties from the Rect collection, I don't think you can really improve it. You may try micro optimizations as doing only one pass and compute yourself `minx`, `maxx`, `miny`, `maxy`...

Comment: intitalize `t, l, b, r`, iterate on all rects, test and update for each variable separately. No lamdas here, just a regular loop on all objects..

Comment: Is there a reason you can't update the bounding rectangle every time you add a new rectangle to the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one loop instead of 4, you may do:

```
cv::Rect result = rects[0];

for (int i = 1; i != rects.end(); ++i) {
    result.tl().x = std::min(result.tl().x, rects[i].tl().x);
    result.tl().y = std::min(result.tl().y, rects[i].tl().y);
    result.br().x = std::max(result.br().x, rects[i].br().x);
    result.br().y = std::max(result.br().y, rects[i].br().y);
}
```